# I want to change the value from 12.56 to 12.57 in python3 (round off)

Tags: python, python-3.x

// Finding circumference of a circle

```
R=2
Z= 2*3.14*R
print(Z)
```

Ans is 12.56

But I want 12.57

Comment: what if answer is 12.58?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the lack of precision in pi. The result of the expression in your code is just 12.56. To get to 12.57, increase the precision.

```
from math import pi

R=2 
Z=2*pi*R 

print(round(Z, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`math.pi`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_pi.asp) instead of `3.14` to be more precise, and then round it to two decimals, since with `math.pi` `Z=12.566370614359172`:

```
import math

R=2 
Z= 2*math.pi*R 
print(round(Z, 2))
>>>12.57
```